# Split-apply aggregation of time series data in R

Tags: r, time-series, aggregate, plyr, xts

I have some weather forecast data, which records the forecast amount of rainfall for every hour. I would like to compare this to observation data, which has the observed amount of rainfall for every 6 hours. So, I need to aggregate the forecast data to 6-hourly data.

Here is an overview of my data:

```
                     DateUtc StationID FcstDay PrecipQuantity_hSum
1        2014-01-01 12:00:00     54745       0                   0
2        2014-01-01 13:00:00     54745       0                   0
3        2014-01-01 14:00:00     54745       0                   0
4        2014-01-01 15:00:00     54745       0                   0
5        2014-01-01 16:00:00     54745       0                   0
6        2014-01-01 17:00:00     54745       0                   0
7        2014-01-01 18:00:00     54745       0                   0
8        2014-01-01 19:00:00     54745       0                   0
9        2014-01-01 20:00:00     54745       0                   0
10       2014-01-01 21:00:00     54745       0                   0
11       2014-01-01 22:00:00     54745       0                   0
12       2014-01-01 23:00:00     54745       0                   0
13       2014-01-02 00:00:00     54745       1                   0
14       2014-01-02 01:00:00     54745       1                   0
15       2014-01-02 02:00:00     54745       1                   0
16       2014-01-02 03:00:00     54745       1                   0
17       2014-01-02 04:00:00     54745       1                   0
18       2014-01-02 05:00:00     54745       1                   0
19       2014-01-02 06:00:00     54745       1                   0
20       2014-01-02 07:00:00     54745       1                   0
...                     <NA>      <NA>     ...                 ...
13802582 2014-11-20 08:00:00     55005       7                   0
13802583 2014-11-20 09:00:00     55005       7                   0
13802584 2014-11-20 10:00:00     55005       7                   0
13802585 2014-11-20 11:00:00     55005       7                   0
13802586 2014-11-20 12:00:00     55005       7                   0
```

To aggregate correctly, it is important to split by `StationID` (the weather station) and `FcstDay` (number of days between date of calculating prediction and the date being forecast) before aggregating.

I have used the `xts` package to do the aggregating and it works as expected if I manually subset the data first e.g.

```
z <- fcst[which(fcst$StationID=="54745" & fcst$FcstDay==1),]
z.xts <- xts(z$PrecipQuantity_hSum, z$DateUtc)
ends <- endpoints(z.xts, "hours", 6)
precip6 <- as.data.frame(period.appl(z.xts, ends, sum))
```

I need to automate the subsetting, but I have tried to wrap the `xts` functions in various split-apply functions and always get the same error:

```
Error in xts(z$PrecipQuantity_hSum, z$DateUtc) : 
  NROW(x) must match length(order.by)
```

This is my latest version of my code:

```
df <- data.frame()

  d_ply(
    .data = fcst,
    .variables = c("FcstDay", "StationID"),
    .fun = function(z){
      z.xts <- xts(z$PrecipQuantity_hSum, z$DateUtc)
      ends <- endpoints(z.xts, "hours", 6)
      precip6 <- as.data.frame(period.apply(z.xts, ends, sum))
      precip6$DateUtc <- rownames(precip6)
      rownames(precip6) <- NULL
      df <- rbind.fill(df, precip6)
    })
```

I've also tried nested `for` loops. Can anybody give any guidance on what's wrong? I've included the code for a reproducible example set below. Thanks in advance.

```
DateUtc <- rep(seq(from=ISOdatetime(2014,1,1,0,0,0), to=ISOdatetime(2014,12,30,0,0,0), by=(60*60)), times=9)
StationID <- rep(c("50060","50061","50062"), each=3*8713)
FcstDay <- rep(c(1,2,3), each=8713, times=3)
PrecipQuantity_hSum <- rgamma(78417, shape=1, rate=20)
fcst <- data.frame(DateUtc, StationID, FcstDay, PrecipQuantity_hSum)
```

Comment: Shouldn't your reproducible example be `data.frame` rather than `cbind`? As it is it creates a character matrix

Comment: I also can't reproduce your error; when I run the same reproducible code I get a data frame with a column V1 that is all `NA`. This seems like a problem, but I also get NAs when I subset for one station before using `period.apply`. Please try running your reproducible example and see if it gives you the same error. (I suspect from the use of cbind that you haven't tried just the reproducible example alone :)

Comment: @DavidRobinson Hmm you are right, I should have tried running the reproducible example first :) Having just given it a go, I am not getting the error described in the post but it also returns an empty `df`. Do you get the same?

Answer (score 0):

I think the error David Robinson is getting is because your example code uses PrecipQuantity_6hSum and not PrecipQuantity_hSum.  Once this is changed your `ddply` code is working for me.

Does this work for you?

```
df<-ddply(
     .data = fcst,
     .variables = c("FcstDay", "StationID"),
     .fun = function(z){
       z.xts <- xts(z$PrecipQuantity_6hSum, z$DateUtc)
       ends <- endpoints(z.xts, "hours", 6)
       precip6 <- as.data.frame(period.apply(z.xts, ends, sum))
       precip6$DateUtc <- rownames(precip6)
       rownames(precip6) <- NULL
       return(precip6)
    })
```

Comment: Ah thank you for the spot, I'll edit. So just to confirm, when you run the `ddply` code it returns a non-empty `df`?

Comment: I get the empty `df` only because that is how `df` is defined initially.  The `ddply` code works.  I think maybe you just need to write `df <- ddply(...`.

Comment: Yeah it works with the reproducible example data, but not with my real data. I guess it's an issue with the data then and I'll need to take a closer look at it. Thanks for all your help.